# Ember form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js, ember-data, ember-validations

I'm kind of new to Ember and I'm on something that should be quite simple. Just trying to validate a form actually.
Using [ember-forms](https://indexiatech.github.io/ember-forms/overview) and [ember-validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations).

Here is the part of the structure, I'll be quite exhaustive so you can get to the point but there is really not a lot of code:

```
 /app
   /controllers
     /admin
       /create-user.js
   /models
     /admin
       /create-user.js
   /routes
     /admin
       /create-user.js
   /templates
     /admin
       /create-user.js
```

First, I'm not sure it's the good structure, especially about the model.

The model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import EmberValidations from 'ember-validations';

export default DS.Model.extend(EmberValidations, {
  entity: DS.attr()
}).reopen({
  validations: {
    entity: {
     presence: true,
     length: { minimum: 5 }
    }
  }
});
```

The controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    createUser() {
      console.log("create");
    }
  }
});
```

The route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('admin/create-user');
  }
});
```

The template:

```
<h3>Create User</h3>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    {{#em-form action="createUser" model=admin/create-user}}
      {{em-input
        label="Name / Entity"
        property="entity"
        placeholder="The name of the user or the entity"}}

    {{/em-form}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I'm missing something and I'm pretty sure it has to do with the model (I tried a lot of thing such as `model=admin/create-user` in the template).

EDIT: there's no error or whatever in the console, the validation is just not called.

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is the fact that you never, anywhere in your code, check to see if the data is valid via:

```
// Somewhere in your controller
this.get('isValid');
```

The second is that you're validations are defined on the controller rather than the model. That works great if your controller extends `ObjectController` (which is now deprecated) which proxies properties automatically to the model.

If you're extending `Controller` and you want to validate the model, you need to define them a bit differently:

```
validations: {
  'model.entity': {
    presence: true,
    length: { minimum: 5 }
  }
}
```

The third is that you're never actually passing an instance of your model to the controller via the route (even though validations should still work):

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // assuming you're using Ember Data
    // find the model with id of 1
    return this.store.find('admin/create-user', 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, just moved the validations in the model, in reopen. That should solve the first and second things you said. So I'll try to do something with the third code you gave me. Thanks!

Comment: @Cohars - The validations can still stay in the controller. You don't need to move them to the model. You just need to include `model.` before the property name.

Comment: Well, I actually find it better in the model. I added ```return this.store.createRecord('admin/create-user');``` in my route, so now my model appears in the ember debugger (of course, it's better). I still can't trigger the validation. Working on it.

Comment: @Cohars - If you moved validations to the model, then your model needs to include `EmberValidations` in its `extends` call. You would then call `model.get('isValid')` from the controller to trigger validations.

Comment: yes, I did include it. I thought ember-validation was validating as the user type, isn't it ? ```model.get('isValid')``` just returns true or false, but I can't know which rule is not respected.

Comment: Plus, it always tells false, so there's truly a problem w/ the template :/

Comment: @Cohars - Validations have nothing to do with the template. After calling `model.get('isValid')`, you can then call `model.get('errors.entity')` to get the actual error message.

Comment: Done, it was just model=model. Seems strange to me. But okay.. Thanks a lot for your help!!